# cannot implicitly convert object to type

Tags: c#

Here is what I want to do

I have a class

```
class A {}
```

there is a function in another class

```
 class B
    {
        int count(object obj)
        {
                conn.table<T>.....   //what I want is conn.table<A>, how to do with obj as object passed to the function   
        }
    }
```

this is how I am calling count

```
B b = new B();
b.Count(a);  // where a is the object of class A
```

Now in count function I want to pass A classname
Now when I do `obj.getType()` I get an error.

Comment: where does `a` come from?  Where is it instanciated?

Comment: what error does `obj.getType()` give you? Always post details of any errors...

Comment: if your error happens at `obj.getType()` why haven't you posted that part of your code?

Comment: And if you can't implicitly convert the object have you tried explicit conversions?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
class B
{
    int count<T>(T obj) where T : A
    {
        // Here you can:
        // 1. Use obj as you would use any instance or derived instance of A.
        // 2. Pass T as a type param to other generic methods, 
        //    such as conn.table<T>(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now.  You're trying to get the type specifier of `obj`

My actual suggestion would be to re-think your design and/or use generics like FishBasketGordo said,

But If you must do it this way, the best way I know is to individually check for different types that obj can be

```
public int Count(object obj)
{
    if(obj is A)
    {
        conn.table<A>.....
    }
    else if(obj is B)
    {
        conn.table<B>.....
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @FishBasketGordo it's an artifact that's also in the OP's code